# How to get url in ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone have a nice way of getting the url of the current page in the controller?

More specifically I need a specific query parameter.

My action looks like this; do I need to put in an argument?

```
public ActionResult Random()
{
    RandomMovieViewmodel rmvm = new RandomMovieViewmodel();
    return View(rmvm);
}
```

Comment: You know that MVC has logic that can pull values out of the URL for you, so you don't need to grab the full URL and parse it yourself? Look into how MVC binds action method parameters. There's plenty of documentation on it.

Comment: Look into Request.Url.ToString() or Request.Url.AbsoluteUri. Like @mason said, there's plenty of ways to do this and a decent amount of documentation on it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using a parameter for this. For example, if you needed an "id" value you could make your method like this: `public ActionResult Random(int id)`. So when you call the controller, like so `mysite.com/Random?id=1`, the value in the url is automatically bound to your parameter of the same name.

However, if you *really* feel like parsing the url, you can call `Request.Url` or, if you are using .Net Core, call `Request.GetDisplayUrl()`.

Comment: hehe, of course I would rather go without parsing the url. If I just want the query parameter, which type should i then take as argument?

Comment: just realised that its the name of the argument that matter and that it casts the variable to that type, never mind

Comment: @s3j80 if it's not what you want you should uncheck it as the accepted answer.

Comment: its quite fine thank you, i was just a bit confused. Made sense as soon as i tried it out